# Delaying regex for more specific matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a scenario where I need to run regex tests on a numeric input that represents phone company operator services.

In one instance, there is a prefix 118 which can act on its own or with a suffix of up to two digits.

At the moment, my function looks something like the below.  My problem is that the least specific '118' exact match fires before the more specific one.

There is no sleep/wait in Javascript and unless I'm mistaken, I don't think I can get setTimeout to return a simple "return true" ?

I don't mind if the answer to this question is in pure Javascript or Jquery, but not having a dependency on Jquery would be preferable.

```
        function isOperatorService(vNumber) {
        var vNumber = vNumber.replace(/\D/g,'');
        if (/^((44){0,1}118[0-9]{3})$/.test(vNumber)) {
                console.log("118 specific");
                return true;
        }
        if(/^((44){0,1}[19]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-79]{1})$/.test(vNumber)) {
                console.log("Other shortcodes");
                return true;
        }  
        return false;
     }
```

**UPDATE:** Re: "Provide your input and expected output."

Pretty much as I described above, in Pseudo-code :

```
if == 118
   wait incase the user has not finished typing (e.g. wait incase 118118...)
else
    do other regex cheks
```

Comment: *"My problem is that the least specific '118' exact match fires before the more specific one"* -- you provide no explanation of specificity.  And your input/output example is not; you provide no input and no output.

Comment: @anubhava see update above.  Basically I think I've got a "race condition", i.e. an exact match for 118 gets fired before the user has a chance to finish typing.

Comment: okay, so it sounds like you need to change your logic to pop your function on something other than onkeyup or equivalent.. change it to something like onblur.  Or, if you *really* want it to be based on the latter.. you can change it to have a variable e.g.  `window.lastKeyPressedTime` variable set with timestamp set on key press and then separately have the function called with `window.setInterval` every 100ms or so and then within your function compare the current timestamp with lastKeyPressedTime`

Comment: @Crayon Violent, at the moment I am indeed using _.on("keyup change blur")_ as triggers.  Your idea sounds interesting, I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Okay well yeah.. the simple solution is to remove keyup from that binding.

Comment: sidenote: i'm just making a speculation because i don't have proper context (clear rules of matching, all possible input/output expectations, etc..) but based on your post, i'm not convinced that your regex itself is solid.  `^((44){0,1}118[0-9]{3})$` means starting at beginning of string, optionally match for 44 (which btw you could have done `?` instead of `{0,1}`), followed by 118, followed by exactly 3 digits, followed by end of sting. This doesn't seem to jive with stuff you mentioned in your post, e.g. calling 118 a "prefix" or optional up to 2 digit suffix

Comment: Also, `[0-79]{1}` maybe you know what you're doing in which case disregard, but to be clear, this will match for a single digit except 8, and not "any number between 0 and 79" I only mention this because all too often I see people who think character classes work like the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a simple debouncer:

```
var timeout;
var typeDelay = 300; // wait after last type
var changeEvents = "propertychange keyup input paste change";

$('#yourinput').on(changeEvents, function () {
    //clear your timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // Add another listener
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        // Do your regex here
        function_ended_typing();
    }, typeDelay);
});
```